# Speeding up join by group in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to fill in missing years per ID. This is easy for the small example below.

```
# Create example data table.
dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                 value = rnorm(10),
                 time = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 6))

# Sort by time variable.
setkey(dt, time)

# Fill in the gaps.
system.time(
dt <- dt[, .SD[J(min(time):max(time))], by=id]
)

# Sort by ID and time, then print.
setkey(dt, id, time)[]
```

Gives

```
> dt
    id      value time
 1:  1 -0.9062227    1
 2:  1  2.0822289    2
 3:  1  0.5073055    3
 4:  2  0.3673813    3
 5:  2         NA    4
 6:  2  0.3726807    5
 7:  2 -0.7381199    6
 8:  2  0.7048979    7
 9:  3 -0.7852230    2
10:  3  0.2327946    3
11:  3         NA    4
12:  3         NA    5
13:  3 -0.3430340    6
```

The years are now continuous and NAs have been added for missing values, exactly what I wanted.

However, this solution takes forever on a much larger data.table.

```
 # Create big example data table
 n <- 1e5
 dt <- data.table(id = rep(1:(n/4), each=4),
             value = rnorm(n),
             year = sample(1997:2001, n, replace=TRUE))

 # Remove duplicate years.
 setkey(dt, id, year)
 dt <- unique(dt)

 # Fill in the gaps.
 setkey(dt, year)
 system.time(
 dt2 <- dt[, .SD[J(min(year):max(year))], by=id]
 )
```

Takes roughly 20 seconds for those ~100000 rows.

I would like to do this for a data table with 100 million rows. There must be a speedier way?

Comment: @eddi you are completely right. Thanks for pointing me towards your answer. Here's the code for my specific problem:
`# Eddi's solution.`
`setkey(dt, id, year)`
`system.time(`
`dt <- dt[setkey(dt[, min(year):max(year), by=id], id, V1)]`
`)`
Basically he's creating a new data.table with just the year sequence variable per ID, then joins to the original data.table. It runs almost instantly.

Comment: **Edited for readability, mods please delete my comment above.** @eddi you are completely right. Thanks for pointing me towards your answer. Here's eddi's solution for my specific problem: `setkey(dt, id, year)` then `dt <- dt[setkey(dt[, min(year):max(year), by=id], id, V1)]` Basically he's creating a new data.table with just the complete year sequence per ID, then joins to the original data.table. It runs almost instantly.

Answer (score 4):

May be this helps

```
 dtN <- copy(dt)
 setkey(dtN, id, year)
 system.time({
  dtN2 <- dtN[, list(year=min(year):max(year)), by=id]
  setkey(dtN2, id, year)
  res <- dtN[dtN2]
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.047   0.000   0.048 
 dim(res)
 #[1] 122958      3

 setkey(dt, year)
  system.time(
  dt2 <- dt[, .SD[J(min(year):max(year))], by=id]
  )
  #user  system elapsed 
  # 20.078   0.035  20.109 

  dim(dt2)
 #[1] 122958      3
```

#### data

```
 n <- 1e5
 set.seed(24)
 dt <- data.table(id = rep(1:(n/4), each=4),
         value = rnorm(n),
         year = sample(1997:2001, n, replace=TRUE))

 dt <- unique(dt)
```